# how to fetch only specific fields from http request in angular 6

Tags: angular

i want to fetch only selective fields from http request made by service. for example name, currencies from the rest url [resturl link](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/united)

**service**

```
 public fetchRecords(name): any {
    const searchParam = 'united';
    const urlPath = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + searchParam;
    return this.http.get(urlPath).pipe(map(
      res => res
      ));
  }
```

**component**

```
getCountries() {
this.service.fetchRecords(this.searchWord).subscribe(res => {
  this.result = res;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with [RXJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) map operator

```
getCountries() {
this.service.fetchRecords(this.searchWord)
.pipe(
  map(data => data.map(({name, currencies })=>({name, currencies })))
)
.subscribe(res => {
  this.result = res;
});
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wutnze)

Answer (score 1):

No you cant, the `HttpClient` only help you to send the request. What would be return is defined in the REST server side code. But you can `map` the result returned into an array of currencies[] :

```
public fetchCurrency(name): any {
    const searchParam = 'united';
    const urlPath = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + searchParam;
    return this.http.get(urlPath).pipe(map(
      res => res.map(({name, currencies })=>({name, currencies})) 
    ));
}
```